# Link in cell using URL from another cell

Tags: google-sheets

On one worksheet I have a table of data that includes an item name, person name, price, and a URL.

On an overview worksheet in question I use the FILTER formula to list the items by person using the following formula: `=FILTER(Data!A2:A14,Data!B2:B14=D2)`. I would like to have this cell also have be hyperlink to the item (if there is a URL in the found row).

Is this possible without a script? (With enough scripting work I'm sure I can do whatever I want but that feels like the hard way)

**EDIT**

I have discovered the [`HYPERLINK`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093313) function which seems to be the key but I cannot get it to work.

At first I put the HYPERLINK function on the inside of my filter like this:
`=FILTER(HYPERLINK(Data!D2:D40, Data!A2:A40),Data!B2:B40=D2)`

However this gave this message: `error: Mismatched range lengths`

Then I thought to combine the URL and text after the filter like so:
`=HYPERLINK(FILTER(Data!D2:D40,Data!B2:B40=D2),FILTER(Data!A2:A40,Data!B2:B40=D2))`

Which worked for the first value in the list but any further cells (that use [`CONTINUE`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093276)) are empty.

**EDIT 2**

I was hesitant to do this at first but [here is a link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOkcv3RcSdTdEVNaEpvRFJlUzRLVzkyc0Nkc2V0UkE&usp=sharing). Just don't tell my family what I'm getting them lol. I went ahead and made a copy so don't worry about messing it up. You can see my attempt at it along a manually created example of what I want it to look like.

Comment: Do you want the URL to appear on the filtered list?

Comment: No, that would be trivial. I would like the text of the cell to be a clickable link as it would appear if the value of the cell was a URL.

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us, and show us the expected outcome?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I was wary about this at first since the contents are "secret" but I highly doubt any of my family and friends will see this question.

Comment: Make sure to buy something for Beth, Wendy and Granny !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were so close !!!!!!!!

Use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   HYPERLINK(
     FILTER(Data!D2:D40,Data!B2:B40=D2),
     FILTER(Data!A2:A40,Data!B2:B40=D2)
   )
 )
```

### Explained

The `ARRAYFORMULA` will take on the ranges, set in the filter, and return the matches.