# Concatenating URL with a value to create link, but links only partially work

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

[image]
I have a column of cells in Google spreadsheet with values such as:

```
b2397  
b9504  
b3333  
b8655  
bxxxx
```

I would like to combine each value with a URL, for example:

```
http://websitex.com?id=
```

From Cell A2, I **auto-filled** all the way down to Cell A6. The problem is whenever I try to click on the links, only the first cell (A2) works and the rest (Cells A3 to A6) that were auto-filled do not. The links that do not lead me to a website stating: "No Such Record" which is not true, because when I try to plug in the formula combining URL and alphanumeric value manually instead of auto-fill, it leads me to the proper link. (I really do not want to do each cell manually...)

Why does it only work for the first cell and not the rest that were auto-filled? I tried someone's suggestion of "find and replace" to possibly refresh the links, but it doesn't work.

Comment: By another thread you mean [Link in cell using URL from another cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52637/88163)? By the other hand add the please add the formula that you tried into your question in order to see exactly how you adapted the referred answer to your needs.

Comment: @Rubén: Sorry, first time poster here so I'm still figuring out this forum. I've now edited and added an image to clarify my question. Thank you.

Comment: Is the site URL correct? The landing page says that the domain is on sale. By the other hand the values that are code formatted have invisible characters after them. Use `=LEN(B2)` to check if your values on the spreadsheet have also invisible characters

Comment: @Rubén. That was just an example site, so the "LEN" formula from "user0" concatenated fine. I actually had that figured out, the problem is...once the URL and alphanumeric values have been combined, the links do not take me to the pages when I click on them.  

I'll let the project sit for another day and look at it again later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), "http://websitex.com?id="&A1:A, ))
```

[image: 0]