# Tie value from one cell to value of another

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to find a way to assign the value of the highlighted portion to the value of the cell to the left of it, so that I can drag the url down and autogenerate the values. Is there a way to assign the highlighted portion a variable "x" and then tie the variable "x" to the number to the left of it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. If you haven't done yet, please read [Add formulas & functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?hl=en). If you need further help, please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating URL with a value to create link, but links only partially work](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/concatenating-url-with-a-value-to-create-link-but-links-only-partially-work)

Answer (score 1):

to obtain something like this:
[image: sample]

the formula to insert in B2 is:

```
=arrayformula (If (A2:A <> "" , "https://metadata.degods.com/g/" & A2:A & ".png" ,""))
```

to show the images, put this formula into C2:

```
=arrayformula(image(B2:B , 1))
```

I found images numbered up to 9999